# Can't install MS Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to install Install MS Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation in XP but during the installation the setup request Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1. 
I have install TFS 2008 SP1, but nothing have change. I can not install  Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 because because the OS is in XP.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as `MS Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation` - are you installing Visual Studio Team Edition, or Team Foundation Server?

Comment: I'm installing Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS 2008 requires Windows Server 2003 SP1 and you can see the editions in the link below
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253078.aspx,
IIS 6 and higher, .Net Framework ,SQL Server 2005 (with Latest Service Pack) or SQL Server 2008 Standard or Enterprise Edition (Enable SQL Server Agent, Analysis, Reporting and SQL Browser services)

I faced this problem and I solved it by installing a virtual machine.
Virtual PC
http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/